# GTK3 file chooser dialog crash using win11

Tags: windows, gtk3

I have install GTK3 3.24.38 from the official website using MSYS2 for a win11 machine.

I am compiling a linux application on a windows machine which work fine except the

gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new() function crashes the system.

I am using minGW gcc 13.2 with VCcode and the application compiles okay and runs except when the file dialog tries to open.

Code is:

```
dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",
                    NULL,
                    GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE,
                    "_Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                    "_Save", GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                    NULL);
```

GDB debug information:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ff8f6fb0137 in glib-2.0-0!g_log_structured_array ()
```

I think there must be a exception but I guess on the windows system the log file is not setup.

I tried passing 0 instead of NULL to see if it was a NULL definition issue but I still get a crash.

Not sure how to setup the log file for GTK in windows.

Thanks. MPC

Call Stack:

```
glib-2.0-0.dll!glib-2.0-0!g_log_structured_array (Unknown Source:0)
glib-2.0-0.dll!glib-2.0-0!g_log_default_handler (Unknown Source:0)
glib-2.0-0.dll!glib-2.0-0!g_logv (Unknown Source:0)
glib-2.0-0.dll!glib-2.0-0!g_log (Unknown Source:0)
gio-2.0-0.dll!gio-2.0-0!g_settings_set_int64 (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_weak_ref_set (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_object_new (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_object_new_valist (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_object_new (Unknown Source:0)
gtk-3-vs17.dll!gtk_file_chooser_native_set_cancel_label (Unknown Source:0)
gtk-3-vs17.dll!gtk_file_chooser_native_set_cancel_label (Unknown Source:0)
gtk-3-vs17.dll!gtk_file_chooser_button_set_width_chars (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_closure_invoke (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_signal_stop_emission_by_name (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_signal_stop_emission_by_name (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_signal_emit_by_name (Unknown Source:0)
gtk-3-vs17.dll!gtk_file_chooser_widget_new (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_weak_ref_set (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_object_setv (Unknown Source:0)
gobject-2.0-0.dll!gobject-2.0-0!g_object_set_property (Unknown Source:0)
```

The open file native dialog works but the save file native dialog does not. This works.

```
native = gtk_file_chooser_native_new ("Open File",
                                      NULL,
                                      action,
                                      "_Open",
                                      "_Cancel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.
You have to create a directory structure that allow gtk to find the schema. With you application in the root directory I created...

```
app-root-dir|
             -share|
                    -glib-2.0|
                              -schemas|
```

You can then copy the compiled schema from the gtk build directory:

> C:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\share\glib-2.0\schemas\gschemas.compiled

into your new application schema directory. The file save dialog is not working.